# How to set attributes in an xml file in Thymeleaf based on a set of conditions

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I need to set attributes in an xml file in thymeleaf based on a set of conditions. My code works, but I want to change the way conditions are checked. Instead of evaluating all possible cases for each attribute (with the use of a ternary operator), I want to set all atributes for a given case (as in typical if-else structure).
Below is the code. How can I change it to set all atributes case-by-case?

```
<confidentionalityCode th:attr="code=(${test}==1 ? 'N' : (${test}==2 ? 'R' : 'V')), displayName=(${test}==1 ? 'normal' : (${test}==2 ? 'res' : 'vres')) " />
```

ChatGPT hinted me this solution, but it produces empty lines wherever the condition is not meet. Is there a more elegant way that would produce an output without empty lines?

```
<confidentialityCode th:if="${test == 1}" th:attr="code='N', displayName='normal'"></confidentialityCode>
<confidentialityCode th:if="${test == 2}" th:attr="code='R', displayName='res'"></confidentialityCode>
<confidentialityCode th:unless="${test == 1 or test == 2}" th:attr="code='V', displayName='vres'"></confidentialityCode>
```